# Symmetry type of non-cohomological automorphic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, random-matrices, l-functions

By Katz-Sarnak philosophy a family of $L$-functions would have a symmetry type which would reflect the statistics of $L$-functions, such as low lying zeros and moments. Shin-Templier's paper on Sato-Tate theorem calculated the symmetry type of many families of automorphic L-functions of varying weight or level, with the assumption that the family of automorphic representations involved are cohomological at the $\infty$-place.

> What is the expected answer for the symmetry type of Maass forms and their symmetric powers? (level and weight aspect)

I am aware of the paper by Alpoge-Miller that Maass forms on $GL(2)/\mathbb{Q}$ of a fixed level and increasing Laplacian eigenvalue should be an orthogonal family. Is there anything known about their symmetric powers and in particular, do we expect them to behave like modular forms? (where it is known that say in fixed level and changing weight, (fixed) even symmetric power of modular forms of weight $k$ form a symplectic family, whereas odd symmetric power of modular forms would form an orthogonal family; cf Duenez-Miller, arXiv:math/0607688)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the following preprint of Sarnak, Shin, and Templier:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5507

In particular, they study "nice" families $\mathfrak{F}$ of automorphic representations. They assume RH and that there exists $A < \infty$, $\delta < 1$, such that uniformly in $n \geq 1$,
\[\sum_{\pi \in \mathfrak{F}(x)} \lambda_{\pi}(n) = t_{\mathfrak{F}}(n) |\mathfrak{F}(x)| + O(n^A |\mathfrak{F}(x)|^{\delta}),\]
where $\mathfrak{F}(x)$ denotes the set of $\pi \in \mathfrak{F}$ of analytic conductor at most $x$. Then they define invariants
\[i_1(\mathfrak{F}) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \sum_{p \leq x} |t_{\mathfrak{F}}(p)|^2 \log p,\]
\[i_2(\mathfrak{F}) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \sum_{p \leq x} t_{\mathfrak{F}}(p)^2 \log p,\]
\[i_3(\mathfrak{F}) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \sum_{p \leq x} t_{\mathfrak{F}}(p^2) \log p.\]

Then $i_1(\mathfrak{F}) \geq 1$ with equality iff almost every $\pi$ is cuspidal. We have $0 \leq i_2(\mathfrak{F}) \leq 1$, with $i_2(\mathfrak{F}) = 1$ iff almost every $\pi$ is selfdual and $i_2(\mathfrak{F}) = 0$ iff almost every $\pi$ is not selfdual (i.e. unitary); in this case, $i_3(\mathfrak{F}) = 0$. We have $-1 \leq i_3(\mathfrak{F}) \leq 1$, with $i_2(\mathfrak{F}) = 1$ iff almost every $\pi$ is orthogonal and $i_3(\mathfrak{F}) = -1$ iff almost every $\pi$ is symplectic.

Here we say that a single automorphic representation $\pi$ is unitary if it is not selfdual, while if it is self-dual, then the completed Rankin-Selberg $L$-function $\Lambda(s,\pi \times \widetilde{\pi})$ factorises as $\Lambda(s,\mathrm{sym}^2 \pi) \Lambda(s,\wedge^2 \pi)$; if the former has a pole at $s = 1$, then $\pi$ is said to be orthogonal, while $\pi$ is symplectic if the latter has a pole at $s = 1$.

So the way to determine the symmetry type of a family of automorphic representations is to use the trace formula to work out what $t_{\mathfrak{F}}(n)$ ought to look like, then use this to calculate $i_1(\mathfrak{F}), i_2(\mathfrak{F}), i_3(\mathfrak{F})$, with this telling you the symmetry type of the family.

Comment: Thanks! I skimmed that paper before but somehow I thought they had the cohomological restriction as well.

Comment: Off topic, but you **do** know that adding tags bumps questions to the front page, right?

Comment: I do know this, and it is unfortunately quite annoying. Maybe there should be a Meta question about whether there's a way to avoid this.

Comment: This has been discussed before on Meta, and it seems to be that edits of any kind should bump questions to avoid unseen vandalism. I would, however, query whether a tag that seems to this non-expert as specialized as "half-integer-weight" is really necessary

Comment: A fair question. In my opinion, yes - the study of half-integral weight modular forms (or more generally metaplectic automorphic representations) is a large enough (and specialised enough) field of study with sufficiently many questions on MathOverflow to merit a tag.

Comment: Sorry to jump into the OT discussion: I think the tagging itself is fine, however there is a semi-official recommendation on meta to limit this type of editing to about three posts a day, to avoid flooding the frontpage. Please keep this in mind for future edits. In addition it would be great if you could write a short tag-wiki for the new tag. If you want to continue the discussion you could join http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/mo-editors-lounge